# Copy ONLY the cells with values (in several columns) - to only ONE column

Tags: vba, excel

I begin the process of streamlining the work, so...

I need a VBA code that copy **only** the cells with value, within a range specified, to ONE column. I want that the effect will be immediate. Once I insert data the column will be update.

**example:**

copy **only** the cells with numbers, within a **range A2:D9**, to **column F**.

- in the real VBA code I don't want it to be limited to a small range, because I have more column then A-D, and they long then 9 rows. So if I could define it a range (but in the code and not in new pop-up windows), this would be an excellent :)
- the COLORS and column G are meaningless. This is just for example.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Thank you for your patience and time...
Appreciate it very much !

Comment: I have not tried much, because i dont know how.
i have many numbers and i continue to insert data and update all the time.

Comment: `I have not tried much, because i dont know how` - Sorry, it's not working here. We are not freelance site. There a many good vba tutorials in internet. Start with [Macro Recorder](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html) and if you get stuck - come back, show us what have you tried and what is not woking and we will be glad to help you.

Comment: Why do you want to do it all at once actually?

Comment: ok...thank you. I'll try to learn from there :)

Comment: dear David, i have many numbers and i continue to insert data and update all the time. After this action, I will filter and check if there is a number that repeated and delete it. finally i do something with all this number. this is for work.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim addedCells As Integer
'
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Set TargetRange = Range("F2:F34")
addedCells = 0
Set SourceRange = Range("A2:D9")
For Column = 1 To SourceRange.Columns.Count
    For Row = 1 To SourceRange.Rows.Count
        If Not (SourceRange.Cells(Row, Column) = "") Then
            addedCells = addedCells + 1
            TargetRange.Cells(addedCells, 1) = SourceRange.Cells(Row, Column)
        End If
    Next Row
Next Column

Calculate
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End Sub
```

Add some parameters to make it dynamic.

Comment: its work great!!! the only problem is that i need to start this code everytime... this is not update automaticlly...

Comment: @user3432087 You could put it in the worksheet change event:Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)